# How to share an argument with system calls on bash?

Tags: linux, bash, system-calls

Actually I don't know much about bash programming. I've read that pipes allows we to use the output of a program as the input of another one. Then I expected that some expression like bellow to works:

```
echo "newdirectory" | (mkdir && cd)
```

Where `mkdir`receives the outputed string from `echo` as it first argument and after `cd` too. The other point is that pipes not executes synchronously from left processes to the right (is that?).

There is a way to reuse an argument through the system calls on bash?

Especially in this case of creating a new directory and change to it.

Comment: Not universally applicable, but you can use `$_` in the example in your question. `$_` expands to the *last* argument of the previous command, so `mkdir "newdirectory" && cd "$_"` would be equivalent.

Comment: @chepner Although the nos answer is more complete and didactic, your comment fills what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables for this, and pass command line arguments to the the two commands mkdir and cd, instead of trying to pipe data to these commands.

```
MYDIR="newdirectory" 
mkdir "$MYDIR" && cd "$MYDIR"
```

With this,

```
echo "newdirectory" | (mkdir && cd)
```

You connect standard input of both mkdir and cd. A program/command need to know 
if it should read data from stdin, and what to do about it. Neither the `mkdir` or `cd` command does this, they expect you to give them command line arguments.

Even in the case the commands could read data from standard input, in this case `mkdir` would consume the input, and not leave anything for `cd`. In other cases where you connect the same pipe to several commands/processes, you cannot determine which one of them would read the data.

Moreover the parenthesis in `(mkdir && cd)` means that the commands are run in a sub-shell. However `cd` affects only the current shell, so you would not be able to observe any effect of the `cd` command.

Answer (score -1):

```
mkdir `echo NewDirectorName`
```

also uses the output of a program as an argument to another program.

Another way to accomplish this is with the `xargs` command.

```
echo NewDirectoryName | xargs mkdir
```

@nos's answer is the most correct for your situation, though.

Comment: You missed the fact that the OP wants the value specified once to be used with `mkdir` *and* `cd`. Command substitution doesn't do anything useful here. `xargs` is for running *one* command multiple times with different arguments, not running *two* commands with the same argument.

Comment: And I stated that the other answer was most correct for the question.  My answer was included for informational purposes since it is related and the syntax is more similar to the OP's code example.